# Google Apps Script - copyrange based on for loop matching

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wAxZROq-HqGSZIeBnOShiLP1x-maCpVhvfr6MKixVZE/edit#gid=1767460404

I am attempting to grab the data in a data range on a data sheet, then loop over that data, match the row values in Column C to the row values in a different (tracker) sheet also located in Column C, and for the matched data, copy the whole row in data sheet to the bottom of the data sheet.

All of this is supposed to be triggered when I enter "Open" in a set field in the status tracker.

What I have done so far (hopefully) is to locate the values to match in the data sheet but I am unsure as to how to use the .copyto function correctly now such that it copys the data to the end of the loop. My code so far: (without .copy.

```
function grabmyRequestID(){  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Status Tracker")

   var searchforrange  = ss2.getRange("C:C")
   var searchfor = searchforrange.getValues()
   Logger.log("Request ID: " +searchfor)
   return searchfor


   }
function findDuplicates(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Status Tracker")
  var ss3= ss.getSheetByName("All Output")

      var sheetNametoWatch = "Status Tracker"
      var columntoWatch = 4
      var valuetoWatch = "Open"
      var searchfor = grabmyRequestID()

          if (sheet.getName() == sheetNametoWatch && range.getColumn() 
               == columntoWatch && range.getValue() == valuetoWatch){

              var data = ss3.getRange("C:C").getValues()


          for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
              if (data[i] == searchfor && searchfor !=""){
              Logger.log('found it')
              }
             }
          } 
        }
```

As you can see, I am running two functions, grabmyRequestID, which grabs the id from the tracking sheet and findduplicates, which matches it with the ids from the data sheet.

I now just want it to copy the whole row where it found the matched column and copy that row to the end of the data sheet. I have tried a few ways but I never actually get any output. I am pretty new to this so I hope somebody can help me out.

I am also not sure entirely sure if my trigger works for this loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: About ``I am also not sure entirely sure if my trigger works for this loop.``, what is the trigger? And I think that when you provide a sample spreadsheet including the input and output you want, it will help users think of the solution of your issue.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I updated the sheet link. My trigger is supposed to be to change the value of column 4 in the "Status Tracker"sheet to Open

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: In `grabmyRequestID`, `searchfor` returns an entire column's data as an array (however many rows long). So `if (data[i] == searchfor && searchfor !="")` will never be evaluated because it is comparing one value `data[i]` against an entire array. If your intention with `searchfor` is return an array rather than a single value, then you need to add a secondary loop so that each value can be compared to `data[i]`. You might also consider only returning both arrays for as many rows as have data.

Comment: @FabianKraus 1) Inconsistent: `grabmyRequestID` gets ColC (Type); `findDuplicates` gets ColD (Requested By) for value = "Open"; "Open" only appears in ColF-J. 2) Incomplete: `findDuplicates` refers to non-existent Sheet="All Output". 3) Duplicates? Focus is "duplicates" yet no code to identify or action them. 4) Nonsense: "What I have done [...] is to locate the values to match in the data sheet". Oh? 5) Coding: "unsure as to how to use the `.copyto` function". Other code (e.g. `myonedit5`) is fine. **Action** What are you actually trying to do, and how? Please re-edit goal:specific and exact.